# Menu items keeps on adding on every menu button press

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

I have added two menu item . Both of them works good but whenever i press menu button new menu items appear beside the old one . Like below u can see

[image]

below is my menu item xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<item
android:title="Search"
android:icon="@drawable/search_white_24dp"
android:id="@+id/searchmenu"
app:showAsAction="always">

</item>
<item
android:icon="@drawable/settings_white_24dp"
android:title="Setting"
android:id="@+id/settingmenu"
app:showAsAction="always"
/>


</menu>
```

and here is my code

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.searchmenu:
            editText = DuwaManager.openSearchBox(this,  
getSupportActionBar(), "DuwaListView");
            break;
        case R.id.settingmenu:

            break;

        case R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            break;
    }
```

please help where i am wrong ?

Sorry this will get to long but , I have second Question

2) My second question i have another menu. xml in which there is share icon in place of search icon , But when i am trying to show on action bar with same code menu item does not show on action bar . below is my another menu xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>
<item
android:title="Share"
android:icon="@drawable/share_white"
android:id="@+id/share_tarika"
app:showAsAction="always"
/>
<item android:title="Setting"
    android:icon="@drawable/settings_white_24dp"
    android:id="@id/settingmenu"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

and its code

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tarika_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.share_tarika:

            break;
        case R.id.settingmenu:

            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: What are you returning from `onOptionsItemSelected()`?

Comment: please help me on second question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu ) {
       menu.clear();// use menu.clear
       MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();    
       inflater.inflate(R.menu."your current activity name ", menu);
    return true;
}
```

use menu.clear()

Comment: and what should i return outside true or false

Comment: for every case return true and for default return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

Comment: Hey check the new solution

Comment: It clears the views present on actionbar every time before recreating the menu.. so if the previous views exist it gets cleared

Comment: thanks it works. But why its create new menu items when it is already there?

Comment: That is how android is designed lets say on performing some actions if some icons should change in your actions bar... so the whole view should get refreshed and oncreteoptions menu will get recalled..

Comment: so i should always use menu.clear() to avoid repeated action item

Comment: menu.clear will wipe out all the existing views on action bar and your inflater will recreate the menu items... so yes using menu.clear you can avoid repeating of menu items on action bar

Comment: please help me on second question

Comment: please repost the 2nd question with the different title... We need to mainitain the community standards.. as the 2nd question is different and solution is different it can't be answered in the same post

Answer (score 1):

The best to do is as this :

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu ) {
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu."your current activity name ", menu);
return true;
}
```

if you have just one menu. Then set menu from Activity page and return true then no need to clear menu. and no duplicate menu will appear.

But if you use two fragment and have to change activity menu as per fragment then only need to clear menu and reset it with new one.

And if you are using onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) in fragment then remove them.